# Modeling the interior and exterior of a polygonal region on the Riemann sphere using Schwarz-Christoffel mappings

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am thinking about the following. I have been involved in a research project involving static magnetic fields inside and outside a polygonal magnetic material. You ended up trying to find a couple of holomorphic functions, one in the interior of the polygon and one in the exterior, but both extending continuously to the boundary of the polygon, and satisfying some "matching" conditions on the boundary.

Without getting too much in the specifics of that problem, I am wondering about the following. If we want to model the interior of a polygon on the Riemann sphere, we could use a Schwarz-Christoffel mapping (S-C mapping, for short) from the unit disk to the interior of the polygon. We can model the exterior of that polygon (including, say, the point at infinity on the Riemann sphere, assuming all vertices of the polygon are finite) using another S-C mapping, from the unit disk to the exterior of the polygon. Note that the S-C mappings extend continuously to the boundary of the unit disks and map the unit circle homeomorphically onto the boundary of the polygon.

But for our model to be complete, we need to know what I like to call the "gluing" map from the boundary of the unit disk which is the domain of the S-C mapping to the interior to the boundary of the unit disk which is the domain of the S-C mapping to the exterior of the polygon.

My question is about that 3rd piece, the "gluing" map. Has it been studied? It is a bit like this. We kind of pushed the polygon onto the equatorial circle of the Riemann sphere, but this came at a price, which is basically the gluing map.

I vaguely remember work of Sato, I think, which may be relevant. So my guess is that this was probably studied. If so, then could someone please provide some references, or a nice answer, or maybe just some comments. In that applied research project, we essentially modeled that gluing map numerically but, for anyone who studied S-C mappings, they know that there is a so-called crowding phenomena, where many preimages of the vertices tend to be very close to each other. This makes a representation using equally spaced points on the circle, like in FFT, not suitable numerically speaking.

Comment: This is just a remark, but it seems to me like this gluing map would definitely have been studied.  Have you tried searching further for textbooks on applied complex variables in electromagnetism?

Comment: @HollisWilliams, I have not, because I do not currently have access to a library. I am under the impression that most such textbooks focus on a single domain (like the interior of a polygon etc), but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Just a remark. Let $P$ be your polygon (supposed to be bounded). Let $f$ be a S-C map of $P$ onto the upper half-plane, and $g$ a SC map of the exterior on the lower half-plane. Then, if the number of vertices is $\geq 4$, the vertices will in general have different images on the real line under $f$ and $g$. You can only assign the images of 3
vertices arbitrarily. This means that for 4 or more vertices,
your gluing map will send some vertices into interior points of the sides, and will be singular at these points.

Comment: By the way, will "the" gluing map not have singularities at points corresponding to vertices that have the same image points on the real line (I know we can have at most 3 of those, in general)?

Comment: If we repeat your reasoning for the inverse of the gluing map, we see that there are also singular points for the inverse gluing map. I presume that their preimages under the gluing map will also be singular points for the gluing map. Are these 2 types of singular points (the ones you have described and the ones I conjectured in this comment) the only singular points of the gluing map? Can we say more perhaps and describe the gluing map by some integral formula perhaps, similar to that for the S-C mapping? I am not sure if such a representation exists though.

Comment: Your remark is true, in principle: the singularities only come from the corners. But the problem is that the gluing map is in general infinite-valued, so the singularities multiply as we perform an analytic continuation, and how to deal with such infinite-valued functions is not clear.

Comment: can you please explain why the analytic continuation of the gluing map is in general infinite-valued? Is this so even for convex polygons, say?

Comment: Schwarz-Christoffel functions are infinite-valued themselves, unless all angles are commensurable with pi. And your gluing map is a composition of a SC-function with an inverse of such a function.